# Get info: sizes displayed in MB first

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

One thing that I miss and would like to have back, is when I get info on one or more files, the size displayed first is not the MB rounded one, it is the size in bytes.

The image below shows on the left what we get with Mac OS X 10.8.2, I circled in red the sizes shown; on the right is what I would like to have back, and what we get with Mac OS X 10.6, circled in green.

[image: size displayed in MB first]

**Is there a way to swap the displayed sizes so that I can have the MB first and in parenthesis get the bytes size?**

By the way, the sizes displayed when in list view are in rounded MB, not in bytes.

Comment: I've never even noticed that before, but honestly I think the way 10.8 handles it is actually the better way. The "size on disk" value is only relevant in some very specific cases, the average user is probably confused by the difference anyway.

Comment: @patrix I'm not after the "better way" :) I would like to change it to *this* way...